# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error? 'NoSuchMethodError' The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried Calling: []("title")

Tags: flutter, dart

Cuando ejecuto esta aplicación, obtengo este error:  ***NoSuchMethodError' The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried Calling:** . Me sale cuando ejecuto la app en mi celular. Me muestra directamente el error en rojo.
Probé modificarlo de diferentes maneras pero no funcionó y de las soluciones que encontré en Internet tampoco me sirvieron. Soy nuevo en flutter y en dart, estoy tratando de aprender, sabes como podría solucionarlo para que la app pueda correr sin problemas? Gracias!

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
//Step 3
  _HomeScreenState() {
    _filter.addListener(() {
      if (_filter.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          _searchText = "";
          filteredNames = titulos;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _searchText = _filter.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }

//Step 1
  final TextEditingController _filter = new TextEditingController();
  final dio = new Dio(); // for http requests
  String _searchText = "";
  List titulos = new List(); // titulos we get from API
  List filteredNames = new List(); // names filtered by search text
  Icon _searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
  Widget _appBarTitle = new Text('Search Example');

  //step 2.1
  void _getNames() async {
    final response = await dio.get(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&language=en-US&page=1');
    print(response.data);
    List tempList = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      tempList.add(response.data[i]);
    }
    setState(() {
      titulos = tempList;
      filteredNames = titulos;
    });
  }

//Step 2.2
  void _searchPressed() {
    setState(() {
      if (this._searchIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
        this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.close);
        this._appBarTitle = new TextField(
          controller: _filter,
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search), hintText: 'Search...'),
        );
      } else {
        this._searchIcon = new Icon(Icons.search);
        this._appBarTitle = new Text('Search a movie');
        filteredNames = titulos;
        _filter.clear();
      }
    });
  }

  //Step 4
  Widget _buildList() {
    if (!(_searchText.isEmpty)) {
      List tempList = new List();
      for (int i = 0; i < filteredNames.length; i++) {
        if (filteredNames[i]['title']
            .toLowerCase()
            .contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
          tempList.add(filteredNames[i]);
        }
      }
      filteredNames = tempList;
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: titulos == null ? 0 : filteredNames.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: Text(filteredNames[index]['title']),
          onTap: () => print(filteredNames[index]['title']),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  //STep6
  Widget _buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: _appBarTitle,
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: _searchIcon,
        onPressed: _searchPressed,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getNames();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildBar(context),
      body: Container(
        child: _buildList(),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Te indica en cuál línea tienes el error? ¿Qué te dice después de TriedCalling?

Comment: No me lo indica en una linea, me lo indica en la aplicación. Osea, en el visual studio code, me dice que no hay errores pero cuando corro la app, se abre y automaticamente me muestra una pantalla en rojo que dice 'NoSuchMethodError' The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried Calling:  []("title"). See also: flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: Tu problema me parece que está cuando creas el ListView después del " return ListTile'. Estás seguro que para todo "index" existe un filteredNames[index]['title']. ¿Podrías asegurarte que index se encuentre en el rango de elementos. Al igual que en el onTap. Lo pruebas?

Comment: Osea sería que borre index, verdad? me sale un error cuando lo hago

Comment: No borres index solo por un if (index < firwtNames. lenggth) { // aquí va la línea actual) } o dentro del Text( index < fin.length ? Fgth : String.Empty)

Comment: También verifica que filterNames[index] != Null, porque va a entrar con índiex=0 y va a pasar la validación. Pero puede que no haya elementos en filteredNamwes[0] y por lo tanto es nulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El  problema es como obtienes los datos. Estas  cargando desde el response.data que contiene dos campos: page y results. El campo results es el  contiene la  infomación, por lo  tanto, tienes que cargar la lista desde este último:

```
  void _getNames() async {
    final response = await dio.get(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=&language=en-US&page=1');
    print(response.data);
    List tempList = new List();
    
// linea actual:    for (int i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
// Linea que debería ser: para recuperar el bloque de datos.

   for (int i = 0; i < response.data['results'].length; i++) {
      tempList.add(response.data['results'][i]);
    }
    setState(() {
      titulos = tempList;
      filteredNames = titulos;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127483/discussion-on-answer-by-juan-carlos-guibovich-como-puedo-solucionar-este-error).